# WP Woocomerce get_shipping_methods method on woocommerce_new_order hook is returning empty array

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

For
WooCommerce Version 7.9.0
testing payments using WooCommerce Order Test - WP Fix It (testing payment gateway)

I have two shipping methods, local pickup and delivery (Flat rate)

Im developing a custom plugin to handle the order data after order payment.
At some point i need to get the shipping method id to check if its an order with a local pickup or flat rate shipping, but the get_shipping_methods is returning an empty array, here is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'send_order_to_external_webservice');


public function send_order_to_external_webservice($order_id) {  

      $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

      $shipping_items = $order->get_shipping_methods(); 
      $shipping_methods = $order->get_shipping_methods(); 
      error_log('Shipping Items: ' . print_r($shipping_items, true)); // returning empty array

      $shipping_methods = $order->get_items( 'shipping' );
      error_log('Shipping Items: ' . print_r($shipping_methods, true)); // returning empty array

    // more code...


}
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: This will mostly happen for pending/onhold orders where the order is created but not yet placed/completed. So, you might want to use a different hook.

Comment: The variable `$shipping_items`is not defined in the 1st `error_log()`! … Also `woocommerce_new_order` has a 2nd variable argument `$order`so you don't need `$order = wc_get_order($order_id);`… I have tested both `$order->get_shipping_methods()` and `$order->get_items( 'shipping' )` and that works... So your issue is related to the code implementation.

Comment: thank you @LoicTheAztec
should i answer my own question. how do i mark your answer as correct ?
this method didnt include the shipping into.
adding 
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'send_order_to_external_webservice', 1,2);
public function send_order_to_external_webservice($order_id, $order) {

solved it.

Comment: @buzibuzi Yes you can answer your own question, as not defined  `$shipping_items` was just a typo error...

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
```

doesnt containt the shipping info.
you need to use the $order param sent in as the second parameter in the woocommerce_new_order method as follows:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'send_order_to_external_webservice', 1, 2);


public function send_order_to_external_webservice($order_id, $order) {  

      $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

      $shipping_methods = $order->get_items( 'shipping' );
      //you can now loop through the shipping methods.

    // more code...


}
```

thank you @loictheaztec for pointing to this.